# Bigbluebutton Setup - ArgumentError 'secret_key_base' for production environment must be a type of string

Tags: bigbluebutton

sudo docker run --rm --env-file env bigbluebutton/greenlight:v2 bundle exec rake conf:check
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: `secret_key_base` for production environment must be a type of String
`/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:583:in`validate_secret_key_base'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:432:in `secret_key_base'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:176:in`key_generator'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:205:in `message_verifier'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.3/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:81:in`block (2 levels) in '
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in`with_execution_control'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in`block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in`run_load_hooks'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:75:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in`instance_exec'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in`block in run_initializers'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in`initialize!'
/usr/src/app/config/environment.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in`require'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsn
ap_lfi'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in`register'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in`require'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in`load_dependency'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in`require_environment!'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/src/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in`'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in`'
Tasks: TOP => conf:check => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Please provide more context, eg. your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run greenlight.
You need to setup BIGBLUEBUTTON_SECRET variable in .ENV file

You can take a look at BBB documentation here (greenlight section): https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/greenlight/gl-install.html